# Retrieving the last record according to date and other record not in the 2nd table in mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2

table1 id is inserted to table2 lead_id

table1

| id | loan_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | valid |
| 2 | 101 | valid |
| 3 | 102 | valid |
| 4 | 103 | valid |

table2

| id | lead_id | lead_status | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | REJECTED | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | 2 | REJECTED | 01/01/2023 |
| 3 | 3 | REJECTED | 01/01/2023 |
| 4 | 1 | REJECTED | 10/01/2023 |
| 5 | 2 | REJECTED | 10/01/2023 |
| 6 | 3 | REJECTED | 10/01/2023 |

what is the query to show loan_id that is not there in table2 and last rejected in table2 according to created

result like -

| loan_id | created |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 10/01/2023 |
| 102 | 10/01/2023 |
| 103 | 10/01/2023 |
| 104 | null |

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: try reading about `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. What should the result look like if the table2 entry is `ACCEPTED` instead of `REJECTED`?

Comment: my query :
select t1.loan_id, t2.created  from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.lead_id where t1.status = 'valid' and t1.id not in (select lead_id from table2 where and lead_status != 'REJECTED') group by t1.loan_id;

this query not fetching the latest rejected record...it is fetching the old one only.
btw ACCEPTED one will not show in the result.

Comment: Add your attempt to your question, not as a comment. What is your not in sub query supposed to achieve? Your example result has loan_id 104 but it does not exist in table1 example. It looks like you are storing your dates as strings. They should be in a column of type `date` and the format `'2023-01-10'`